# assign value of service property (Angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I try to assign a property of a service object by using the `$http` but I have confusing results. Why this doesn't work (here is my code):

```
.service('config', function ($http) {
    var config = {
        get_host: function () {
            if (online == 0) {
                return offlineHost;
            }
            return onlineHost;
        },
        online: 'false',
        host: 'false',
        checkConnection: function () {

            //this wont work;
            /* 
            $http.get(this.host + http_url ).then(function(response) { 
                return  response.data.ping;
            });
            */

            //this will work 
            return 'oke';
        },

        _load: function () {
            this.host = this.get_host();
            this.online = this.checkConnection();
            this.url_api = this.host + http_url;

            if (this.online == 1) {
                this.offline_message = 'Maaf aplikasi tidak bisa terkoneksi dengan server atau anda offline';
            }
        }
    };

    //run constructor and get value;
    config._load();

    return config;

}) //end config class
```

In my controller :

```
var online = config.online;
alert(online) //return undefined, but the $http request on firebug is showed return value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `$http` service calls are asynchronous.

The easiest way to handle this is to make your service return a promise:

```
return $http.get(this.host + http_url);
```

(`return` in front of `$http` is crucial here). Then anywhere in the code:

```
config.checkConnection().then(function(response) { 
    // there you get the response.data.ping
});
```

See your modified and simplified code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/cCHXCLCG3xJUwAPPlJ3x?p=preview

You can read more about that:

- http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/
- http://lennybacon.com/post/2014/03/21/chaining-asynchronous-javascript-calls-with-angular-js
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 1):

service:

```
.service('config', function ($http, $q) {
var config = {
    get_host: function () {
        if (online == 0) {
            return offlineHost;
        }
        return onlineHost;
    },
    online: 'false',
    host: 'false',
    checkConnection: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get(this.host + http_url ).then(function(response) { 
            $q.resolve(response.data.ping);
        });

        return $q.promise;
    },

    _load: function () {
        this.host = this.get_host();
        this.online = this.checkConnection();
        this.url_api = this.host + http_url;

        if (this.online == 1) {
            this.offline_message = 'Maaf aplikasi tidak bisa terkoneksi dengan server atau anda offline';
        }
    }
};

//run constructor and get value;
config._load();

return config;

}) //end config class
```

controller:

```
config.online.then(function(data){
    alert(data);
    var online = data;
    handleDate(online); // this is a predefined function to handle your data when it's downloaded
});
```

Comment: i try your suggestion but what make me confuse is in this point : 

`var online = config.online.then(function(data){
    data.response;
     //this alert is working
     //alert(data.response);
     
    });

  //this alert not work (return object)
  alert(online);`

Comment: sorry i cannot vote u up, my rep > 15 
but thanks anyway